# Copy a folder from D drive to a USB flash drive using robocopy

Tags: windows, robocopy

How do I copy folder T in D drive to a flash drive (H) using robocopy?

When I try to copy files to my USB flash drive in the normal windows way, the copying process keeps getting paused and I have to unpause it every now and then, making copying frustrating and inefficient. Thats why I now try do copy using robocopy.

But in the command window, when I try with:

`c:\>robocopy "D:\T" "H:" /e /w:1 /r:2 /COPYALL`

I get an error:

**NOTE : Security may not be copied - Destination might not support persistent ACLs.
ERROR : You do not have the Manage Auditing user right.
*****  You need this to copy auditing information (/COPY:U or /COPYALL).**

Comment: This question is better suited for [su], as it has nothing to do with programming. Also, the error message is pretty clear. **You do not have the Manage Auditing user right. *You need this to copy auditing information (/COPY:U or /COPYALL).*** What part of that don't you understand? Either grant yourself the Manage Auditing right, or remove the `/COPYALL` from the robocopy command.

Answer (score 0):

USB drives are generally win32 format. You need to format it is NTFS to allow for all the file attributes to be stored on the drive.